# Why color, size and weight is not changing by ranger

Tags: javascript, html

Why this is not working. The size, weight, color not changing. I created a label and some range input to change its size, weight and color.

Html

```
<label class="main" id="word">Sample input</label>
            
        
            <label for="text">Text: </label>
            <input type="text" name="text" id="data" placeholder="Type your word"><br>
<label for="s">Size: </label>
            <input type="range" name="s" id="size" from="10" to="50"><br>
            <label class="we"for="w">Weight: </label>
            <input type="range" name="w" id="weight"><br>
            <label for="c">Color: </label>
            <input type="color" name="c" id="color">
```

JavaScript

```
var text = document.getElementById('word');

var data = document.getElementById('data').value;

var size = document.getElementById('size').value;

var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

var color = document.getElementById('color').value;

text.style.color = color;
text.style.fontWeight = weight;
text.style.fontSize = size;
```

Comment: Your code sets the styles once upon page load. You'll need to execute the JavaScript when the slider changes, by way of an event listener.  See [EventTarget.addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have make some steps to make your code works:

**Step 1:** Bring all of your code into a `changeStyle()` function and put it into `onchange="changeStyle()"` in all of `<input>` tag. And I run `changeStyle()` on init page also to make it set your sample data by current data from HTML.

**Step 2:** Fix `.style.fontSize` range by set the value to `size + 'px'`.

**Step 3:** Fix HTML attributes `from="10" to="50"` to `min="10" max="50"`. You can find out more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range).

```js
function changeStyle() {
  var text = document.getElementById('word');

  var data = document.getElementById('data').value;

  var size = document.getElementById('size').value;

  var weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

  var color = document.getElementById('color').value;

  text.innerHTML = data;
  text.style.color = color;
  text.style.fontWeight = weight;
  text.style.fontSize = size + 'px';

}

changeStyle();
```

```html
<label for="text">Text: </label>
<input type="text" name="text" id="data" placeholder="Type your word" onchange="changeStyle()" value="Sample input"><br>
<label for="s">Size: </label>
<input type="range" name="s" id="size" min="10" max="50" onchange="changeStyle()"><br>
<label class="we" for="w">Weight: </label>
<input type="range" name="w" id="weight" min="10" max="600" onchange="changeStyle()"><br>
<label for="c">Color: </label>
<input type="color" name="c" id="color" onchange="changeStyle()">


<br/><label class="main" id="word" onchange="changeStyle()">Sample input</label>
```